# Am I using clp-java correctly

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming

The problem I want to solve with [clp-java](https://github.com/quantego/clp-java) is

```
Minimize 4 - 2 * x1 + 6 - 2 * x2 where x1 <= 2, x2 <= 3
```

The code is

```
CLP clp = new CLP();
CLPVariable x1 = clp.addVariable();
clp.createExpression().add(4).add(-2, x1).asObjective();
clp.createExpression().add(x1).leq(2);

CLPVariable x2 = clp.addVariable();
clp.createExpression().add(6).add(-2, x2).asObjective();
clp.createExpression().add(x2).leq(3);

clp.minimize();

System.out.println("obj=" + clp.getObjectiveValue());
System.out.println("x1=" + x1.getSolution());
System.out.println("x2=" + x2.getSolution());
```

The result of execution is

```
obj=-16.0
x1=2.0
x2=3.0
```

Obviously the result should be 0 and not -16. Am I missing something?

I am using version 1.16.11

Comment: After playing around with it, the conclusion I arrived at is that the lib (or the underlying dll) has some issues with constants and minimization. If you replace the constant `4+6` with a bounded variable `[10,10]` it seems to work.

Comment: This issue has been fixed with the latest commit.